# Read resource file failure

Tags: vb.net, winforms, file, resources

In my VB.Net application there is a piece of code which reads the data from the resource file and updates it in the DataBase.
Code is as below,

```
Myobj.staus=my.resourceclass.status_name
Myobj.enddate= datetime.now
...
Myobj.saveobject()
...
```

This code is deployed in production. Issue is sometimes for some records status not updated, it's empty and date is correctly updating. But I'm unable to reproduce this issue locally. I doubt if it's not reading data from resource file.
Because there is no other place we update this status. At the same time date is updating to db as well.

Comment: If `status` is a property, have you made sure that there is no condition in the setter stopping the value from being updated? If you are using .NET Framework's built-in resource system I think it'd throw an exception if it for some reason couldn't read them, rather than returning an empty string/null.

Comment: There is no condition, the status flag is set directly on resx file. We read this file and asign to status property of the class object.

Comment: And the worst part is it happens only in production environment and also not always only for some records.

Comment: Well somewhere something goes wrong. You should look into [Remote Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp) so that you can debug your project properly. My guess is that the problem is in the `saveobject()` method.